# проблема со отображением mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

После установки mediawiki у меня не отображается skin при посещении открытии сайта т.е. только текс, стек таков php7.3, postgres 12 ну и самая актуальная mediawiki, что делать и куда смотреть не знаю, по оф документации не удалось выудить необходимую проблему, при установке самого сайта также не было проблем. по умолчанию skin "Vector" включен включил.  Буду благодарен за подсказку.

[image: пример работы сайта]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пробелему решил с помощью установки из исходников актуальной версии php (было 7.3 --> стало 7.4.3) + переустановил движок mediawiki. Теперь все отображается нормально.